Flutter convert DateTime to String with timezone offset
What I expect result is 2024-09-06T14:28:26+0800
DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(DateTime.now()）
But result is 2024-09-06T14:28:26Z

This question is similar to: How do I format DateTime with UTC timezone offset?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The easiest way to get the format you want is to use package:timezone, convert your DateTime to a TZDateTime, and use .toIso8601String on it. It's exactly the format you want.
